# how to set value in protractor test for select?

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, protractor

Trying to set a new value for my (title) select(combo) in my protractor test in chrome:

```
  element(by.model('title')).click().sendKeys('mrs');
```

However I am getting this error:

```
 UnknownError: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (325, 542). Other element would receive the click:..
```

This is what my select looks like:

```
<select name="title" required="" class="form-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-valid-required" data-ng-model="title" data-ng-options="title.id as title.name for title in titles"><option value="" class=""></option><option value="0">Mr</option><option value="1"> Mrs</option></select>
```

How can I set my option in this test?

Comment: Could you show the relevant HTML code of the `select` element? Thanks.

Comment: dude see above cheers